# Add a new line in a <td>

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to put a newline in an editable `<td>` element when Alt+Enter is pressed. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong in the below code.

```
_onkeydown: function(e) {
            let which = e.which;
            if(which === 13) {
                if(e.altKey) {
                    console.log(e);
                    console.log("Alt+Enter");
                    mytdelement.textContent += "\n" + " ddd";//String.fromCharCode(which);
                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //Do somethig else
                }
            }
        },
```

I have to override the default enter behaviour, so when the user presses `Alt+Enter`, that should add a new line as the `Enter` keypress would have done.

Comment: You need to add some HTML, like `<br>`, `\n` doesn't create a new-line on the page. Notice also, that [UIEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which) is deprecated, use [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

Comment: @Teemu I am modifying the text content of the element, so putting `<br>` may not be useful. I have tried this.

Comment: @mplungjan granted I should have a detailed working example, but I have already provided a code snippet and I think the question is clear. Will try to make a working example.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you're modifying the text content. I said it's not possible to add a new-line to a TD element using `textContent`. You will need to add a HTML element instead, or style the cell with [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) or something similar, that could cause other issues, though.

Comment: OK, if that solution causes harm, you can always do something like in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzf34kLm/).